# Configure UFW to allow only established and related conections (on IPv4)

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ufw

I want to configure ufw to deny everything except the related and established connections.  On iptables I usually did :

```
  -P INPUT DROP
  -P FORWARD DROP
  -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I read that the next code on ufw is closely related:

```
 ufw default deny incoming
 ufw default deny forwarding
 ufw default allow outgoing
 ufw allow 443/tcp
 ufw allow 53/tcp
 ................
```

The problem is, with that ufw code I'm allowing ALL the traffic incoming from that ports. With iptables, only the established connections were allowed.
How could I configure the same rules on ufw?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you don't need to do anything to allow ***RELATED/ESTABLISHED*** Connections.

In ***ver. 0.36 of UFW*** I'm looking at on ***Ubuntu Core 16.04***, the rules to allow RELATED/ESTABLISHED connections are there by default.

Crack-open the ***before.rules*** rules, you'll see the job has been done for you:

```
# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

`ufw` is considered as a simple frontend for `iptables`. It does not support all the functionalities provided by `iptables` and filetering based on matching state of connection is not supported yet.

`ufw` was basically initiated so that any user can understand or edit the basic firewall rules without having to go through the complexities of `iptables`. You can check this [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) to get more idea on which features are supported yet. Note that if you know `iptables` then there is no need for `ufw`.

Comment: I know iptables, the problem is that NetworkManager conflicts with iptables. I try every solution listed at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution_.231_-_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces 
But the issue persists.... :(

Comment: @marttt: your problem with iptables is that you can't save-restore the rules?

Answer (score 1):

Try add to /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: My /etc/ufw/before.rules contains the following lines:

```
# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Shouldn't this have the desired effect?